# help with a join and group

Tags: php, mysql

There's got to be a way so that this only uses 1 query. I'm assuming using a join and a group by

Here's my current code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `databases` where `id` in (select `id_database` from `categories`)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   echo $row['name'] . '<br />';

   $sql_c = mysql_query("select * from `categories` where `id_database`='" . $row['id'] . "'");

   while ($row_c = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_c))
   {
      echo $row_c['title'] . '<br />';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is... something like this should do the trick.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from databases db JOIN categories cat on (db.id=cat.id_database) ORDER BY db.name");

$last_name = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   if( $row['db.name'] !== $previous_name ) {
       echo $row['db.name'] . '<br />';
       $previous_name = $row['db.name'];
   }
   echo $row['cat.title'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.name, c.title from databases as d, categories as c where d.id=c.id_database;
```

Comment: only thing is i need to echo the database `name`, and then a list of  the `categories` in that database...

Comment: so just iterate over the result set and echo the name of the database only when it's different from the one before. Just like Lee suggested ...